# Comentários diferentes em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ide, comentários

Percebi que, pelo menos no Notepad++, comentários na linguagem JavaScript são tratados de duas formas diferentes, os quais são marcados com duas cores.

Quando eu uso `//` e `"/*` ... `*/` aparece em verde e quando uso `///` e `"/*` ... `*/` aparece em azul, conforme a imagem abaixo.

[image: IDE com comentários destacados]

Existe alguma coisa diferente entre esses tipos de comentários? Podem ser utilizadas algumas diretivas assim como usamos em outras linguagens para orientar na hora da compilação dos códigos?

Comment: O '//' é somente um comentário, o '///' serve para sumarizar um método. Ao chamá-lo, aparecerá o sumário, junto com os parâmetros e o retorno (se houver). (Utilizo C#. Como não sei se isso se aplica para o JavaScript, apenas comentei).

Comment: `///` e `/**` são comentários de documentação. Não consegui descobrir se há uma padronização no ECMAScript sobre isso ou é uma convenção. O [JSDocs](http://usejsdoc.org/about-getting-started.html), o PHP e outra linguagens usam este padrão.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O comentário com 3 Barras, pode ser utilizado para identificação de métodos. Por exemplo, no `Visual Studio 2017`, ao digitar 3 barras, a `IDE` automaticamente cria um sumário onde eu posso identificar seus parâmetros, retornos, etc...

```
/// <summary>
/// Faz algo com o metodo cliente
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Código"></param>
/// <param name="Nome"></param>
/// <param name="Desativado"></param>
public void Cliente(int Codigo, string Nome, bool Desativado)
{
  //Faz alguma coisa
}
```

A vantagem disso é que eu posso "esconder" o excesso de código e identificar-lo apenas lendo o seu nome.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que seria interessante destacar o "PODE" na resposta. A diferença entre os comentários não é intrínseca da linguagem; para o JavaScript todas as formas são meros comentários. A diferença é aplicada apenas no editor. Ou seja, a resposta correta é "não tem diferença para o JS, mas para o editor PODE fazer diferença".

Answer (score 4):

Não, não há nada em JavaScript que torne o comentário de três barras em algo diferente. Outras linguagens usam assim, em JS no máximo você pode considerar isto como diferente, mas para a linguagem é o mesmo que fizer isto:

```
// /comentário aqui
```

Não há nada na especificação do EcmaScript, e até onde eu sei nenhuma implementação considera isto como especial.

Disseram sobre o C# e é verdade que ela tem significado especial na sintaxe, mas na prática muda nada para o código em si.

O que deve ocorrer é o editor acabar usando esta regra de outra linguagem em JS para decidir sobre o *highlight*, o que de certa forma é uma falha, por outro lado pode ser útil dar este destaque para quem usa esta notação informalmente. Alguns utilitários de documentação usam este padrão para indicar que é um comentário de documentação e não de código em si, então acaba sendo útil o editor tratar de forma diferente.

O que eu acho curioso é o Notepad++ tratar essa suposta documentação com a mesma cor do comentário com início e fim, eles têm semântica opostas, por isso talvez seja até acidente o que ocorre com as três barras, algo emprestado indevidamente de outra linguagem, certeza só perguntando para os devs do Notepad++.

Answer (score -1):

Basicamente:

"/* */"  => Para quando vc quer escrever mais de uma linha de comentário

"//" => Para comentários em apenas uma linha

Já li a respeito desses comentários que ajudam ao compilar apenas em c#...

Não sei de nada sobre isto acerca do Javascript.

uma dica! baixe o microsoft vs code! ahaha

Comment: Sim, essas diferenças eu uso. Porém a minha dúvida é quando uso "\\" e "\\\" (2 barras ou 3 barras) que são apontadas com cores diferentes. Gostaria de saber se existe alguns comandos internos onde possamos usar as três barras...

Comment: hmmm compreendo, estranho pois eu nunca havia visto este tipo de coisa no javascript. Aqui no vs code, quando utiliza 3 barras ele fica na mesma cor de comentário normal, o que me leva a crer que eles está considerando a terceira barra como parte do comentário.